# Browser resolution and size is smaller than the screen's ones

Tags: google-chrome, browser, frontend

When I want to style my React Project with scss, the width and haight elements are not correspoding to the real size. Changing the browser did not solve the problem. After using https://screenresolutiontest.com/ it said that my screen resolutin is: 1536 x 864, but my screen is: 1920 x 1080. What could be the problem?

Something that I tried and kinde worked was changing Scale and Layout to 100% insted of 125% Recommended, my primary PC does not need such changes.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue, This is how it works for everyone . If browsers were to use native resolution then all text/content will be very small. Say font size is 12px on a desktop 1920 x 1080 screen it might be readable but on mobile with same resolution it wont be readable.

So to fix that mobile browsers emulate lower resolution.

This article goes in depth on how it works https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a mobile device, however this is somewhat understandable on mobile, despite the fact some other (less confusing) method could be employed. Have also noticed that on 3 different (1080p native resolution) displays, on two different (1080p native graphics hardware) desktop machines (Windows and Linux), that both Chrome and Firefox do render at 1536 x 864 pixels.

Edit: After looking a little further into this, the issue appears to be related to, in these instances anyway, operating system level UI scaling.